# Altering the values of a pandas dataframe based on cell value causes data not to plot correctly

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pandas

I have a data set in which negative values exist, these are indicative of incorrect measurements.

I've tried to set these values to 0 using:

```
gTemp36[gTemp36['S22  50cm'] < -99]= 0
```

However when I try to plot this data the graph doesn't plot correctly as shown [here (the graph on the right)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UewYf.jpg).

I've tried using `.dropna()` on the `DataFrame` before plotting but it doesn't seem to improve things, does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set them to `nan` instead of zero, your plot correctly plots them at zero.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that I could change them to `NaN`, I used `gTemp36[gTemp36['S22  50cm'] < -99]= np.nan` and the plots display correctly!